# Match the year and quarter from Date and paste the vaues

Tags: excel, vba, copy, match

I have been striving to find a way which perform the following Match and calculations but could not find something similar.

I am beginner to VBA all i want is that.

`Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("B4")` is date which is **(02-31-2020)** and `Sheet2` have some data as like below attached picture.

Now i want that code will match **Col"Year"** and **Col"Quarter"** by matching the date, so the `Sheet1 date` expresses that **year is 2020** and **Quarter is 1** so the code will copy values from `Col"E"` and `Col"G"` which are ahead of same year and quarter as per the date.

and paste that values into `Worksheet("Sheet3").Range("G10:H10")`

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, better specify which to be your input. A date from Sheet1? Active cell value? If the date should be "31-2-2020", which will never exist (in February), should the code extract the year and the quarter and use it like reference to search in the second sheet?

Comment: FaneDuru, Yes You are right i have changed the Date reference to "02-31-2020" Yes! code will extract the year and the quarter and use it like reference to search in the second sheet.

Comment: Then, please try the code I posted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It starts from the active cell of "Sheet1" where a date must be found:

```
Sub testFindDateQAndCopy()
  Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, lastR2 As Long
  Dim procDate As Date, Qdate As Long, yDate As Long, arr2, i As Long
  
  Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
  Set sh3 = Worksheets("Sheet3")
  lastR2 = sh2.Range("B" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row

  If Not IsDate(sh1.Range("B4").Value) Then _
        MsgBox "In cell """ & sh1.Range("B4").Value & """ it is not a date...": Exit Sub
  procDate = sh1.Range("B4").Value 
  Qdate = Int((Month(procDate) - 1) / 3 + 1)
  yDate = Year(procDate)

  arr2 = sh2.Range("B2:G" & lastR2).Value
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr2)
    If arr2(i, 1) & arr2(i, 2) = yDate & Qdate Then
        sh3.Range("G10:H10").Value = Array(arr2(i, 4), arr2(i, 6))
        Exit For
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you it is working fine @FaneDuru but I want this thing dynamic that whatever the date is in Sheet1 range code will covert it in Year and Quarter to match it in Sheet2, Beacuse the current code is just working for "02-29-2020" Feb

Comment: @Learning: Not really... It is enough to have a (any) date in the active cell!

Comment: Can you please add the range("B4") instead of Active cell please.

Comment: @Learning: Of course, but for such small modification it should be good to try it by yourself... Only trying you can learn! Now, I will adapt it... Did it and I commented the line checking if the active sheet is Seet1. Not necessary, enymore...

Comment: This error comes even i am on the activecell. https://ibb.co/vqJrMJk

Comment: @Learning: This only should mean that the active cell value **is  not a date**. Can you post here which is the cell value? Is it a string?

Comment: Yes i tried to change it by procDate = sh1.Range("B4") but still having an error.

Comment: @Learning: You previously asked for "B7"... I adapted the code with "B4". But it works only if it is a date in that cell. If it is a string, possible to be converted, please post it here.

Comment: Right Thank you so much i understand your point.

Comment: @Learning: So, does it work or still make tests?

Comment: @Learning: I edited the code and adapted it to warn in case of no date in that specific cell...

Comment: Thank you sooooooooo much for the consistent help. Code is working great

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper column that combines `Year` and `Quarter` like `2020Q1` eg using a formula (because match can only match a single value but not 2). Then use the [WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match) to match that helper column with what you got from your date `=YEAR(A1) & "Q" & ROUNDUP(MONTH(A1)/3,0)` where A1 is your date `31-2-2020`.

Another solution can be if the return values have only numeric numbers and no text you can use the `SUMIFS` function:

```
=SUMIFS(E:E,B:B,YEAR(A1),C:C,ROUNDUP(MONTH(A1)/3,0))
```

to retrun the value from column E. Here no helper column is needed, as `SUMIFS` supports multiple criteria.

Comment: Thank you for the help you provided @Pᴇʜ but i am looking for solution in VBA because the thing i have posted is 5% of my work which will be attached to original code. So i need this thing in code.